# fit_transform PCA inconsistent results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to do `PCA`  from `sklearn` with `n_components = 5`. I apply the dimensionality reduction on my data using `fit_transform(data)`.

Initially I tried to do the classical matrix multiplication between `pca.components_` values and my `x_features` data, but the results are different. So I am wether doing my multiplication incorrectly or I did not understand how `fit_transform` work.

Below is a mock-up to compare classic matrix multiplication and `fit_transform`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
np.random.seed(0)
my_matrix = np.random.randn(100, 5)`

mdl = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
mdl_FitTrans = mdl.fit_transform(my_matrix)
pca_components = mdl.components_
mdl_FitTrans_manual = np.dot(pca_components, my_matrix.transpose())
mdl_FitTrans_manualT = mdl_FitTrans_manual.transpose()
```

I am expecting `mdl_FitTrans == mdl_FitTrans_manual` but the result is `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out, how the `transform()` method is implemented in sklearn: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a5ab948/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L101

According to it, manual reduction is done as following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(100, 100)
mdl = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
mdl_fit = mdl.fit(data)
data_transformed = mdl_fit.transform(data)
data_transformed_manual = np.dot(data - mdl_fit.mean_, mdl.components_.T)

np.all(data_transformed == data_transformed_manual)

True
```

Comment: so  basically I just needed to center my data before doing the multiplication. Thanks.